# Maximum between int and long long int inside std::max function VS '>' operator

Tags: c++, templates, max, std

I have two vectors "a" and "b" of long long ints, and I wish put the difference of respective elements of "a" and "b" into a vector "c". But I don't want these differences to go below 0.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<long long int> a={360757931684,484141693549}; 
    vector<long long int> b={186119101678,675563431537};
    vector<long long int> c; 
    vector<long long int> d;

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        // c.push_back(max(0,a[i]-b[i]));
        c.push_back(max(0ll,a[i]-b[i]));
        //I need to use "0ll" to make this work, Because the commented line above doesn't work
    }
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        if (a[i]-b[i]>0)
            //Here this works fine even without "0ll"
            d.push_back(a[i]-b[i]);
        else
            d.push_back(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

While using `std::max` function I had to use `0ll`, but while using `>` operator using only `0` was sufficient. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because [std::max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) must be given two parameters of the exact same type, whereas `int` and `long long int` are two different types. If you write `std::max(0, a[i]-b[i])`, it will not compile, because the type of `a[i]-b[i]` is `long long int`, and the type of `0` is `int`.

Longer answer:

`std::max` is a function template. The overload you are using has one template parameter `T`, and two parameters `const T& a` and `const T& b`. When you call `std::max`, you can explicitly specify the template parameter like this.

```
std::max<long long int>(0, a[i]-b[i])
```

In this case, the compiler will generate a function that receives two `long long int`s, and you can actually pass anything convertible to `long long int` to the function.

However, if you do not specify the template parameter `T`, [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) will try to deduce it for you.

Here is how it works. The first parameter is `const T& a`, so the compiler tries to deduce `T` based on what you passed as an argument. You pass `0`, so the compiler deduces that `T` is an `int`

Then the compiler tries to deduce `T` using the second parameter `const T& b`. You passed a `long long int`, so the compiler deduces that `T` must be a `long long int`.

The compiler then fails to instantiate the function template because it deduced conflicting types for the same template parameter.

Failing to instantiate the function template `std::max` with the specified arguments, the compiler fails to find a matching function to call, that's why you are getting a compile error.